# When do you use indicator random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

One of the most difficult concepts that I can't seem to get my head around are indicator random variables. I understand what they are and I understand what to do. But when I am faced with a question, I never think to use them. When do you actually use indicator random variables in statistics questions such as estimation questions, questions about random variables and probability distributions etc

Thanks!

Comment: In the most basic sense, you use indicator variables when you are interested in probability: $P(A)=E(I_A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indicator random variables are most useful when working with problems involving Expectation (and Variance, Covariance, &c.) because they make use of the *Linearity of Expectation* to greatly simplify problems.

---

A binomial distributed random variable, $X\sim\mathcal{Bin}(n,p)$ is the count of successes in a sequence of $n$ Bernoulli trials with success rate $p$, and  has the pmf: $$\mathsf P(X{=}x)~=~\dbinom n x ~p^x~(1-p)^{n-x}\;\Big[x\in\{0,..,n\}\Big]$$

The expectation is thus: $\mathsf E(X) = \sum\limits_{x=0}^n \dbinom n x ~x~p^x~(1-p)^{n-x}$

Now, there are techniques to find a closed form of this series, but if we use Indicator Random Variables, $X_i$, for the success for the $i$-th trial, we *immediately* simplify the problem to:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X) ~ = & ~\mathsf E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) \\[1ex] = & ~ \sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i) \\[1ex] = & ~ n~p \end{align}$$

And so forth.